# How to run these 2 javascripts at the same time in html

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the first bit:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        window.onload=function(){
        var strLinks = '';

        for (var i = 1; i <= 23; i++) {
        strLinks += '<li><a><img src="chapter_1/'+ i +'.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>';
    }   

        document.getElementById("pages").innerHTML = strLinks;
    }
    </script>
```

And the second bit:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload=function(){
    var strLinks = '';

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    strLinks += '<option value="http://google.com">link '+ i +'</option>';
}   

    document.getElementById("chapter").innerHTML = strLinks;
}
</script>
```

The first one would basically add images automatically and the second one would add links automatically as well until the loop ends. However when I try to put these two together, the first one won't run at all. 
How do I get both of these to run?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :)

Comment: in first you define `window.onload = ....` and in second you **re**define `window.onload=...`

Comment: How did you "try to put these two together?"

Comment: I hope to learn a lot here!

Comment: What should it be in the 2nd part?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of assigning (and overwriting) the property directly.

```js
addEventListener('load', myFunction);
addEventListener('load', myOtherFunction);

function myFunction(event) {
  document.body.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode("some text")
  );
}

function myOtherFunction(event) {
  document.body.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode("some other text")
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can only have ***one*** `onload` function. Therefore, do the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function(){
    var strLinks = '';

    for (var i = 1; i <= 23; i++) {
        strLinks += '<li><a><img src="chapter_1/'+ i +'.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>';
    }   

    document.getElementById("pages").innerHTML = strLinks;

    strLinks = '';

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        strLinks += '<option value="http://google.com">link '+ i +'</option>';
    }   

    document.getElementById("chapter").innerHTML = strLinks;
}
</script>
```

Also, please remove magic numbers like '23' and '5'. User variables to define these values.

Comment: Thank you! I'm fairly new to this so I don't completely understand yet the lingo used in the other answers.